# Use Application.Resources in Class

Tags: wpf, resources

I do not know how to use a defined Application Style Resource in code.
I have defined:

```
<Application.Resources> <Style x:Key="OrangeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
```

I am using this resource in the XAML section of my application like:

```
<Button Name="Button_Start" style="{StaticResource OrangeButton}" Margin="0">
```

and it is working fine, and I can also change the Button Style by code

```
Button_Start.Style = CType(FindResource("RedButton"), Style)
```

but only in the VB file that was automatically created when I created my new project. If I add a new class file and try do the same it says:

```
Name 'FindResource' is not declared
```

My problem is therefore, how to make use of Application resources in all the different class files in my application.

Peter

Answer (score 3):

The [`FindResource`](http://swp.corp.lloydsnet/Pages/Default.aspx) method is defined by the [`FrameworkElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.aspx) class, so it will only be available if your class extends that or you have an instance of `FrameworkElement` from which to start your resource lookup.

However, if you know your resource resides at the `Application` level, you can use either [`TryFindResource`](http://swp.corp.lloydsnet/Pages/Default.aspx) or [`Resources`](http://swp.corp.lloydsnet/Pages/Default.aspx) as follows (C#, but should be easy to infer the VB):

```
object resource;

if (Application.Current.TryFindResource("RedButton", out resource))
{
    Style indirectStyle = (Style)resource;
}

//or use this
Style directStyle = Applications.Current.Resources["RedButton"] as Style;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer, I am not sure I understand all you are writing, but I have it to work now with the code

```
    MyButton.Style = CType(Application.Current.Resources("GreenButton"), Style)
```

Very nice.
Peter